# Cell broadcast support on Android?

Tags: java, c++, android, android-ndk, telephony

Does anyone know if there is a support for [cell broadcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_Broadcast) on Android?
If yes, can anyone point me to any example that shows how to use it? (e.g. receive messages on some channel)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few sites that come up on google about this..

I think there are restrictions in certain countries - Brazil for instance will only allow you to use channel 50 (from what I read).

http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android+cell+broadcast